# Email problems / 100% Failure Notices errorcode 550

Tags: magento2, email

I hope someone can help us or can give us a tip or direction how to solve the next problem?

We started using the standard build in email from magento 2. Only we found out a lot/most emails that customers would receive goes directly in their spam folder because fe. Google mention "Gmail cannot verify that this message was sent by copyshopdehaan.nl (and not by a spammer)"

After a heavy discussion for 4 weeks with our supplier they recommended a SMTP extension so we went for Aitoc's SMTP which being installed. After installing and we did setup all credentials/ports etc we got only failure notices after magento 2 sends automatic order, invoice, contactform emails, all came back with error code 550;

91.184.19.251 failed after I sent the message.
Remote host said: 550 Messages should have one or no Content-Type headers, not 2.

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.
Return-Path:
Received: (qmail 2976 invoked from network); 27 Aug 2020 16:49:59 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO 93.90.187.184) (webstore@copyshopdehaan.nl@[93.90.187.184])
by 172.17.0.4 with ESMTPSA (DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 encrypted, authenticated); 27 Aug 2020 16:49:59 -0000
Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2020 16:49:55 +0000
From: CustomerSupport Copyshop De Haan

Please if you have some tips, thoughts etc we would appreciate these!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, try to disable that extension and test with another one, since there is more free SMTP extensions. If the problem persists, try to disable the other installed extensions and see if one of them is causing the issue. You can try to re-check all the config done in the plugin, see if it's the latest version and check the compatibility with your Magento version. Might help to start looking for where the problem comes from.

Comment: The MX record for your domain shows your service provider as the authoritative mail server https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3acopyshopdehaan.nl&run=toolpage changing smtp on your magento server will not fix this. You will either need to relay mail via your service provider (preferred) or amend the mx records so that your server is responsible for mail delivery/receipt formyour domain.